# Easy way to avoid writing similar codes manually

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to write a code which will look like this:

```
private void letterA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    function(A);
}

private void letterB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    function(B);
}
```

and it goes on for all English characters.
Is there any easy way that doesn't require writing it all manually, like a code generator, to do this?

[image]

This is how it looks and I want to code all buttons.

Comment: Just write one event handler and then bind different controls to it.  Why duplicate code, by hand or automatically?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Can you please write an example? I'm not much familiar with event handler.

Comment: What is `A` and `B` in your sample code?

Comment: There are buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you are looking for this:

```
private void letterA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // or as Button, as TextBox - whatever actual type you want
  function(sender as Control);
}
```

and put all the `Click` event handlers from `letterA`, `letterB` etc. to this method

Comment: I should add them all to function() method?

Comment: @farshad: assign `Click` events for all `letterA`, `letterB` etc. controls to this method